# Service Worker push event data is null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, service-worker

I would like send data on my `fetch` event in the Service Worker.

My POST for send push event with firebase :

```
return fetch("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization:
      "key=XXXX"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    registration_ids: [token.subscriptionId],
    data: {
      title: "Foo",
      body: "Bar"
    }
  })
```

When i look the `console.log(event.data)` in my service worker, it return `null`.

I don't understand why :/

Anyone have already send push notification with data ?

Thank you community !